# Pine Script language syntax

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I just start to learning Pine Script. And I cant find any information about this issue in language documentation or google. This code is working and I find it in someones indicator script.

I want to understand what this means:

1. `if (float)`
2. 

```
float = float ? float : float
    
float ph = ta.pivothigh(prd, prd)
float pl = ta.pivotlow(prd, prd)
    
float lastpp = ph ? ph : pl ? pl : na
    
if lastpp
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?:` is called [ternary operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Operators.html#ternary-operator).

The way it works is, it will check a condition and return `value1` if the condition is `true` and return `value2` otherwise.

```
condition ? value1: value2
```

You can write the same check with an `if` block as below:

```
if (condition)
    value1
else
    value2
```

### Edit:

`ta.pivothigh` will return `NaN` if there is no pivot. `NaN` is not a number so when you run it in a condition it will return `false`.

Essentially, what `ph ?`  checks is to see if there is a pivot high or not.

Comment: Yes, I understood what is '?:' operator. I don't understand how float type can be conditon.